# Transaction receipt is always null in getTransactionReceipt in geth

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

Following is a promise that i use for getting transaction receipt:

```
function getTransactionReceiptMined(web3Instance, txHash, interval) {
    const self = this;
    const transactionReceiptAsync = function(resolve, reject) {
        web3Instance.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash, (error, receipt) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            } else if (receipt == null) {
                setTimeout(
                    () => transactionReceiptAsync(resolve, reject),
                    interval ? interval : 500);
            } else {
                resolve(receipt);
            }
        });
    };

   return new Promise(transactionReceiptAsync);
}

function sendRawTransaction() {
...
  let sendRawTxn = async function(resolve, reject){
//web3_inst is web3 object
        web3_inst.eth.sendRawTransaction("0x" + txSerialized.toString('hex'), function(err, result){
          if(!err){
            getTransactionReceiptMined(web3_inst, result)
            .then(function(receipts){
                resolve(receipts); 
              })
            .catch(function(error){
                reject(error);
              });
          }else{
            reject(err);
          }
        });

});
}
```

The above code works when i deploy in (local)ganache and (online testnet)ropsten. But when i deploy in geth, i get following output in (powershell) console:

> O [03-28|12:05:27.873] Submitted contract creation
>   fullhash=0xaeacbabebdec3ca0d3e89e4030abc644d34ad34ad46d1eaf803abb31fa852913
>   contract=0x9F35a8B2ACE175734FA94059F59dA792123049cC INFO
>   [03-28|12:05:29.793] Commit new mining work                   number=1
>   sealhash=9f591d…f29cb5 uncles=0 txs=10 gas=44098370 fees=0.04409837 
>   elapsed=5.907ms

Normally the promise calls itself few times until it receives `receipt` object, but in case of geth, even after receiving the above output which i assume to be `contract deployed successfully`, the promise is stuck in infinite loop as `receipt` is always null. How should i solve this?

PS:
I am using solc to compile and deploying using nodejs i.e., no truffle.
    node version: v10.14.2
    web3 version: 0.20.7

```
PS C:\> geth version
Geth
Version: 1.8.23-stable
Git Commit: c942700427557e3ff6de3aaf6b916e2f056c1ec2
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.11.5
Operating System: windows
GOPATH=
GOROOT=C:\go
```

Genesis file:

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 15,
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "gasLimit": "0x260000000",
  "difficulty": "0x24",
  "coinbase": "0x20a876ab4b2e27e1918275859de895e1b87a2f8f",
  "alloc": {
    "0x20a876ab4b2e27e1918275859de895e1b87a2f8f": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000"
    }
  }
}
```

### **Update:**

After a while a checked this on console:

geth output:

> INFO [03-28|15:12:08.916] Submitted contract creation
>   fullhash=0xfb8ddf2536ff5475d6f8ccde47b5dfb1cfea909a0eccfff76857b86e7da44a88
>   contract=0x9e46d590F6aa8a7166CB43fBB1e9AFa58BDe3C3e
>    INFO [03-28|15:12:11.217] Commit new mining work number=1
>   sealhash=478732…a3cfc0 uncles=0 txs=1 gas=4409837 fees=0.004409837
>   elapsed=1.097ms

geth console:

```
> eth.getBlock("latest")
{
  difficulty: 36,
  extraData: "0x",
  gasLimit: 10200547328,
  gasUsed: 0,
  hash: "0xd887ca627fcd6959ede6c41e51a7da1c84eb6ccddf0b1974bb8938c45ae358bf",
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: "0x164259641d660616aa4a96201f98971604ff0b38",
  mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: "0x0000000000000000",
  number: 0,
  parentHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  receiptsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 506,
  stateRoot: "0x0b7d3ec854a52e42499a0ccf0fbbab8365a7ac7e3c9f36022e5b42aec8a2f3f1",
  timestamp: 0,
  totalDifficulty: 36,
  transactions: [],
  transactionsRoot: "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421",
  uncles: []
}
> eth.getBlock("pending")
{
  difficulty: 131072,
  extraData: "0xda83010817846765746888676f312e31312e358777696e646f7773",
  gasLimit: 10190585857,
  gasUsed: 4409837,
  hash: null,
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  miner: null,
  mixHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  nonce: null,
  number: 1,
  parentHash: "0xd887ca627fcd6959ede6c41e51a7da1c84eb6ccddf0b1974bb8938c45ae358bf",
  receiptsRoot: "0xb7500c085957fa5e7ba88aff60dc536d93cf73913659e47bfdc637bc8e9eb94e",
  sha3Uncles: "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347",
  size: 17152,
  stateRoot: "0x75fd4a128345f0df147f93795780f7706821fa9bba79132f6e9085fab33c6115",
  timestamp: 1553766110,
  totalDifficulty: 0,
  transactions: ["0xfb8ddf2536ff5475d6f8ccde47b5dfb1cfea909a0eccfff76857b86e7da44a88"],
  transactionsRoot: "0x1df68167a72101fabe050fb21c8bbd87a8321100f1e959ba5cd46c74dc067fd0",
  uncles: []
}
>
```

I think, that the transaction is not getting mined even after waiting for an hour. Also, please explain why difficulty of pending block (131072) is different than that of network (36, which i had set in genesis).

**

### Update

**
Until now, I have been doing `geth ... --mine`, but when I do `geth ... console` then `miner.start()` then it starts creating blocks:

```
INFO [03-29|14:13:23.907] Successfully sealed new block            number=3172 sealhash=74b181…41550f hash=dbba06…c3dba8 elapsed=4.693s
INFO [03-29|14:13:23.919]  block reached canonical chain          number=3165 hash=5622f9…35038a
INFO [03-29|14:13:24.085]  mined potential block                  number=3172 hash=dbba06…c3dba8
INFO [03-29|14:13:24.103] Commit new mining work
```

Is there any difference between using command line `mine` vs `miner.start()` ?

Comment: `when i deploy in (local)ganache and (online testnet)ropsten. But when i deploy in geth` - this statement doesn't make much sense, because those 3 entities are not under the same category. Ganache and Geth are node types, while "local" and Ropsten is a network types. In order to describe a deployment, you need to specify both, i.e., what node type you're using and to what network type you're deploying. So while `local ganache` provides a good deployment-description, `(online testnet)ropsten` doesn't, and neither does `geth`.

Comment: I meant in sense of install location, i.e., geth(one node) and ganache on pc, whereas ropsten testnet (endpoint) from infura.

Comment: Just say which setup works and which doesn't. At present, I see 3 node types and 2 network types, so there are 6 possible setups, and I'm pretty sure that you've tried only some of them, so please explain which combinations you've tried and what result you get for each combination.

Comment: I tried on:
1. geth local
2. ganache local
3. ropsten testnet (endpoint from infura)

Comment: And the result in each case?

Comment: Results:
 ganache & ropsten: i can receive receipt object in few seconds.
geth: receipt is always null

Comment: So 2 and 3 are OK, while 1 is not OK?

Comment: How did you obtain `txHash`? (please post the code in your question).